# App for a check of an elderly person

Tags: ios

I'm looking for an **iOS application** that would work as a **heartbeat** (in the [programming sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing)) of the word) between 2 people/devices and that would help monitor the well-being of each other (or at least one of the party).

#### Purpose

I want to know that my elderly relative (**person** from here on) is OK by knowing the last time he/she interacted with his/her phone.

#### What it should do

- Whenever a person **interacts** with the phone in some way (screen unlocking seems like the best type of interaction), it would send a heartbeat signal to at least one other paired device whose owner would be able to see the last time the person used his/her phone. It should be completely transparent and not require any other manual action from the person.
- *(optional)* The other party would receive a notification when a certain threshold of minutes since the last heartbeat signal was surpassed.

#### What it does NOT need to do/be

- Track/display location of the person.
- Monitor the vital functions of the person (like the heartbeat in the medical sense of the word).
- Send an emergency message.
- Be a messaging application.

### What I came up with so far

- I found some applications that simplify to elderly people contact with their relatives when they feel lonely or something.
- I know that iOS devices can share their location between family members or friends.
- I thought of applying automation, e.g. using "App opened" trigger and then Pythonista's "Run script" or "Run script over SSH" action which I could program but that's clunky and it annoyingly displays a notification every time it runs which apparently cannot be suppressed so it would annoy the person.
- Things like detection of phone unlocking does not seem to be part of iOS' public API and I assume there might be other restrictions so maybe such an app cannot even exist.